# What's wrong with this amount and Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I am passing **122.385** as an amount to paypal and the response is

> The link you have used to enter the
>   PayPal system contains an incorrectly
>   formatted item amount.

Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of decimal places needs to be exactly what the payment vendor is expecting, it seems that paypal expects to be given a rounded figure of 2 d.p.

Reference: https://www.x.com/message/118673?tstart=0